# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 407633920) (tried to allocate 16063 bytes)

Tags: wordpress, memory-management, wordpress-theming, out-of-memory, fatal-error

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 407633920) (tried to allocate
>   16063 bytes) in /xxx/wp-content/themes/ancoraunite/fw/core/core.wp.php
>   on line 1185

The line 1185 looks like this:

```
$rez[$opt['prefix_key'].($slug)] = ($opt['level'] ? $opt['level'].' ' : '').($name).($count ? ' ('.($count).')' : '');
```

I tried lots of things like changing wp-config memory limit, making changes in php.ini, changing wp-settings, but of no use. Can anyone please help, I am new to this.

Also please check php.ini config here:
http://bjpmirabhayandar.com/info.php

Answer (score 1):

Refer below options,

1. define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' ); in your wp-config.php file
2. If you can edit or override the system php.ini file, increase the memory limit. For example, memory_limit = 128M
3. If you cannot edit or override the system php.ini file, add php_value memory_limit 128M to your .htaccess file.
4. If neither of these work, it’s time to ask your hosting provider to temporarily increase PHP’s memory allocation on your account. Keep in mind that most decent hosting providers allocate 64 MB to PHP under each account, and most decent hosting providers allow users to temporarily increase the memory allocation. If your hosting provider won’t accommodate you, perhaps it’s time to find a new hosting provider.

Finally above options not working you need to override core file. because I also face this problem and I can't solve without override core. Could not overriding by  .htaccess or something else.

In wp-include/default-constants.php line number:36

define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
change to define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );

Comment: Tried all of these..nothing worked..seems to be problem with this code..any suggestions ?

Comment: did you try last option?, the core edit.. In wp-include/default-constants.php line number:36

Comment: I think your server MEMORY_LIMIT is less.  are you using shared server ?.. Contact server support and ask them to increase.

Comment: Yes I contacted them..they asked to buy additional RAM

Comment: Lol. All the best